# DNS server redirect domain to another server?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I have a domain, say `cheese.com` and it has an A record of say `10.10.10.10` for `*.` and `.` and I want to move `cheese.com` to a new server, but the problem is I can't easily change the DNS A record to point to `10.10.10.11` the new server. Is there a way to set it up so when people go to `cheese.com` it goes to `10.10.10.10` which then forwards them to `10.10.10.11` until I can get the A record switched over?

Comment: In order for anyone to actually be able to answer this question with making all kinds of wild guesses and assumptions, you'll need to define "when people go to" somewhat more precisely than you have so far.

Comment: When people visit cheese.com I want it to go to `10.10.10.10` which redirects them to `10.10.10.11` via some sort of browser or DNS system so that it looks like the A record is set to `10.10.10.11`

Comment: `the problem is I can't easily change the DNS A record to point to 10.10.10.11 the new server` - Why not?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about serving web pages, you can set up a reverse proxy on 10.10.10.10 to forward to 10.10.10.11. There is plenty about it on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming http, aka "web" connections):

You can make the web server send either a 301 redirect or an http meta redirect to point to the new server when people connect. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection for more details.